# Connect button does nothing when adding MS SQL connection in Apache Superset

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, apache-superset, pymssql

I am trying to add Microsoft SQL Server as a new connection via SQLAlchemy URI.

URI looks like this: mssql+pymssql://user:pass@host:port/database

All required drivers and libraries are installed on Docker container.

Test connection promts "Connection looks good!"

But when I press CONNECT button - nothing happens, no matter how long I wait.

Other non-MS databases connect and are working just fine.

I am not even sure where to begin. Maybe I could add a connection via console, but could not find how to do it.

Comment: In the backlog I find the following:

Unable to load dialect <class ‘sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.adodbapi.MSDialect_adodbapi’>: type object ‘MSDialect_adodbapi’ has no attribute ‘dbapi’